# Subtract two dates stored as varchar

Tags: oracle, datetime, type-conversion

I have 2 varchars like:

```
20160316131824
20160316080002
```

How can I subtract to see if there is more than 24 hours of difference between the 2 values?

I tried using the symbol `-` but it gives me an error. What is the best way?

Comment: You will want to convert the varchars to date time first, then do the time comparison.  This answer shows how to get the varchar to a datetime.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841773/convert-datevarchar-and-timevarchar-to-datetime-oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample query to convert the given varchar2 value to date and calculated the difference in hour.

```
select (to_date('20160316124052', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')-to_date('20160316080002', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))*24 DateAndTime from dual;
```

**Update**

```
SELECT (sysdate-to_date(START_TIME,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))*24 FROM LOGGING WHERE NAME='TERR_PAST' AND UPPER(STATUS) = 'EXECUTED';
```